# Android: How to get images from camera without storing a file?

Tags: android, camera, storage, ram

I'm using the system's activity to get an image from camera.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST);
```

When the user accept the photo I use this callback

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bitmap bp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            /*
             * DO SOMETHING WITH IMAGE ...
             */
            getContentResolver().delete(data.getData(), null, null);
        }
    }
}
```

The last line deletes the file stored by the system.
It works but is it avoidable the use of mass storage (with the corresponding `uses-permission`)? I'd like to get the image from RAM, process it, then returning the method leaving all to garbage collector.
I wouldn't want the photo to be visible from gallery meanwhile the processing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to get images from camera without storing a file?

Use the camera APIs directly (`android.hardware.Camera`, `android.hardware.camera2.*`).

Right now, you are delegating the camera work to a third-party app. There are hundreds of pre-installed camera apps on the ~1.5 billion Android devices, and there are hundreds (perhaps thousands) more available on the Play Store and elsewhere. The user could choose to use any of those to handle your `startActivityForResult()` call. What those apps do is largely up to them. If they wish to save the image to disk in addition to returning the `"data"` thumbnail, that is their choice, not yours.

Comment: I see, thank you. Then my last chance is to make a custom camera inside my app using the API

Comment: Please, which of them is the one for my purpose?

Comment: @user3290180: `android.hardware.camera2.*` is only available on Android 5.0 and higher. If your `minSdkVersion` is 21 or higher, use it. Otherwise, you will need to use `android.hardware.Camera`.

Comment: But keep in mind, if you access the camera directly, you have to acquire the `android.permission.CAMERA` permission. So you have to choose ....

Comment: thanks, I already use that permission because the existence of a camera is critical to my app.

Comment: it is odd that the official guide on the website explains how to use the deprecated version...

Comment: @user3290180: Google marks things as deprecated way too early IMHO. If your `minSdkVersion` is less than 21, you have no choice but to use the deprecated API. The documentation is probably aiming at what developers are likely to need to use today, given that Android 5.0+ devices are presently ~10% of the market.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't provide a File uri as a location for the image when you start camera intent then the system will not save the image. As with this configuration your image is already stored in the memory and will no longer be used (garbage collected) once you lose reference to it.

Comment: It doesn't need an uri, the system generates an uri with the timestamp and stores a file. I would avoid that.

Comment: if I remove the last line and go to gallery I can see the same image taken in the app